# What is "!functionname()"?

Tags: javascript, function, call, operator-keyword

I was looking for some example code for JS, and I found something that used `!function()` and I was wondering what exactly is the exclamation for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` is the boolean not operator. `!function()` converts the return value of `function()` to boolean and returns its opposite value

Answer (score 2):

If you are substituting the word "function" for the name of a function, it simply means "negate the result of the function".  The `!` means not.  So

```
!true == false
```

Answer (score 1):

`functionname` is an expression (which presumably evaluates to a function-object) and the result of this evaluation (a function-object) is invoked with `()` which invokes the function and evaluates to the return value.

Now, this return value (which was the result of an expression) is then negated with the [unary `!` (not) operator](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/operators). The rules for `!` are `!truthy -> false` and `!falsy -> true`, where `truthy` and `falsy` are concepts covered ["truthy and falsy" in JavaScript](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript).

The example could be written as: `!((functioname)())`, but that's just silly

Answer (score 1):

Tried this:

```
var a = !function () {
            alert("notfun");
            return "nottestfun";
        }

alert(a);
```

It alerts:

```
false
```

and nothing else.  If you try to run a(), you get a type error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'a' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

Comment: Because it's not. Remember that `function () {}` (in an expression context, which it is in the in example) is just returning a function-object which is being negated right away! (`var a = !someFunctionObject`) Since an object is a `truthy` value then that is the same as `var a = false` and `false()` is just silly. If you wanted to *evaluate* the function and apply `!` to that... `var a = !(function () {alert("notfun"); return "nottestfun"})(); alert(a)` -- happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It's a negation. So if `function()` returns a boolean value, the `!` negates it.

Not sure how JS governs naming (the `$` is legal), so it could also just be the name of the function :P (I've since checked, and it appears that since `!` is an operator, it's not legal, so this is *not* a possibility).

Comment: The only non-alphanumeric characters allowed in names are `_` and `$`.

Comment: @Reid but oh, they do get used a lot. Javascript is not my specialty.